# Declaring multiple variables on one line

Tags: c#

What does the first line of this code mean? What is happening?

```
int n, r, sum = 0, temp;
            Console.Write("Enter the Number: ");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            temp = n;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                r = n % 10;
                sum = (sum * 10) + r;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            if (temp == sum)
                Console.Write("Number is Palindrome.");
            else
                Console.Write("Number is not Palindrome");
```

Answer (score 4):

The variable are all being declared in one line, but only `sum` has an initial value. All the other variables need to be assigned before they are used.

You can test this out here: [Try .Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet)

This compiles:

```cs
int n, r, sum = 0, temp;

n = 1;
r = 2;
temp = 3;
Console.WriteLine($"n = {n}");
Console.WriteLine($"r = {r}");
Console.WriteLine($"sum = {sum}");
Console.WriteLine($"temp = {temp}");
```

this does not:

```
int n, r, sum = 0, temp;

Console.WriteLine($"n = {n}");
Console.WriteLine($"r = {r}");
Console.WriteLine($"sum = {sum}");
Console.WriteLine($"temp = {temp}");
```

Comment: you are right. Just tested it... wow I just learned something new - really though, zero is the default.

Comment: Values are not assigned defaults expect for at the class level. So if it was a class member it would have a value of zero, even without setting it.

Comment: it wasn't even my question :-)